# jsp:forward works but jsp:include doesn't

Tags: eclipse, jsp, servlets, include

I couldn't find an answer anywhere so I'd appreciate any help.

When I use:

```
<jsp:forward page="/myservlet"/>
```

it works fine, but when I use

```
<jsp:include page="/myservlet"/>
```

it doesn't.

Error says it couldn't find the fragment at path: MyProject/WebContent/here

It is obviously mapped because forward works just fine.
Any ideas?

Comment: What error? Just a log message or an actual exception?

Comment: If the error comes from Eclipse, don't trust it. Deploy, test, and see if it works.

Comment: message says: it couldn't find the path and 
error: FileNotFoundException

Comment: @JB Nizet, cannot run it because exception prevents my page from loading.

Comment: Tell us more about what you're doing. What is the complete error message/stack trace? What are you doing to get this message. Where does it appear? It's still not clear if it's an Eclipse message or a message from the web container.

Comment: *"Stack trace or it never happened!"* :)... seriously, it is not clear. Maybe include a bit of code from your custom servlet as well. We are eager to answer your question if you provide more information.

Comment: Alright, I'm stupid. I looked into stack trace once again and the problem wasn't the servlet but the file it was connecting to. It had the wrong path. I don't know how I missed it the first time. Thanks for all the hints guys. Once again, im stupid -_-

Comment: Then the initial info that *forward* works was not correct? Nvm, glad you've solved the problem.

Comment: I wanted include so when eclipse gave me the error I typed forward instead and the error disappeared. Since I didn't want forward, I never fired it. So yeah, I think it didn't work as well, just no error somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You can think in jsp:forward as the same as Request Dispatcher forward, it sends the request to another resource, the include in the other hand works different it send the request to another resource and go back to the sender, when you are using the jsp:include commonly is to include other jsp fragments in your JSP and this include is for each request, if you want to include this fragments as compilation time of the JSP you must use the include directive.

So the error is find if you see the attribute of the include says **page=""** because you need to specify another JSP Page.

If Your Servlet returns a file you can dynamically add using the `<c:import>` of the jstl core library.

Comment: The servlet I want to include, includes a file. I want the output where I call the servlet.

Comment: If Your Servlet returns a file you can dynamically add using the `<c:import>` of the jstl core library.

Comment: Not sure where are you going with this answer. But if *forward* works, *include* should work as well. The only exception is if OP is making nested *forward* in that included resource, which is AFAIK not allowed. But the described error message does not fit that situation.

Comment: The error says "Error says it couldn't find the fragment", include works different of forward, and include expects a "page" as parameter